# Docker installation failing on Virtual box OracleLinux 8

Tags: docker, gpg-signature, oraclelinux

I am getting below error on running :

```
sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

warning: /var/cache/dnf/ol7_latest-31ccda58762f86b1/packages/libcgroup-0.41-21.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
Oracle Linux 8 Latest (x86_64)                                                                              3.0 MB/s | 3.1 kB     00:00    
GPG key at file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle (0xAD986DA3) is already installed
The GPG keys listed for the "Oracle Linux 8 Latest (x86_64)" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: libcgroup-0.41-21.el7.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

OL8 comes with Podman and podman-docker package that effectively aliases the docker command to podman. See installation doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/podman/podman-install.html